# Extract URL from two types of lists

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

I have to extract a special URL from two types of lists.

**wav_list_01.txt:**

```
http://www.example.com/3277rdsh6721vs2981fg66_453.wav?ID=8572145"
http://www.example.com/3277rdsh6721vs2981fg66_1234.wav?ID=8572145"
http://www.example.com/3277rdsh6721vs2981fg66_89.wav?ID=8572145"
http://www.example.com/3277rdsh6721vs2981fg66_356.wav?ID=8572145"
```

In this type of list the correct URL is always the one with 4 digits after the underscore:

```
http://www.example.com/3277rdsh6721vs2981fg66_1234.wav?ID=8572145"
```

I can accomplish this with the following grep command:

```
grep -o 'http[^"]*_[0-9]\{4\}.wav?ID=[0-9]\{1,\}' wav_list_01.txt
```

Now to the problem. I also have to extract a special URL from another type of list.

**wav_list_02.txt:**

```
http://www.example.com/83d72jd72bnx27887f2s34_9.wav?ID=0942145"
http://www.example.com/83d72jd72bnx27887f2s34.wav?ID=0942145"
http://www.example.com/83d72jd72bnx27887f2s34_5.wav?ID=0942145"
```

In this type of list the correct URL is always the one *WITHOUT* the underscore and single digit:

```
http://www.example.com/83d72jd72bnx27887f2s34.wav?ID=0942145"
```

Is there any way I can modify the above grep command to work with wav_list_02.txt also? if not what is the next best solution to handle both lists in the same script?

The script will run in a dash shell so the solution need to be POSIX compliant, preferably also clean and simple.

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION:**

With the help from Thalmann the solution was found:

```
grep -o 'http[^"]*_[0-9]\{4\}.wav?ID=[0-9]\{1,\}\|\|http[^_]*?ID=[0-9]\{1,\}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use the not operator '^' and say that it can be everything but not the underscore - if match you have your URL- it is something like '[^_]*' everything that is not a underscore.

Insert that with the 'or' operator in you above grep command, and it will tak eboth the file with the four digits and if their is no underscore included.
Remember to escape the or operator like this: '\|'

Comment: But then it will not work with wav_list_01.txt, or I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Okay i think i am misunderstanding your question, you want both files to match with one regex?

Comment: Exactly, one regex to match both files, if it's possible